# PhpStorm, Windows 10 PowerShell and Git commands

Tags: php, powershell, phpstorm

I'm using PhpStorm on windows and I'm trying to learn working with CLI.

So in the Program settings I use Windows PowerShell as native Terminal.
I installed git, node and npm.
I'm very new on using the command line on Windows.....

When using the PowerShell as standalone the command `git --version` gives me the correct git Version. When using the same command in PhpStorm Terminal which is linked to the PowerShell I get an error (sorry for German):

> "git : Die Benennung "git" wurde nicht als Name eines Cmdlet, einer Funktion, einer Skriptdatei oder eines ausführbaren Programms erkannt. Überprüfen Sie die Schreibweise des Namens, oder ob der Pfad korrekt ist (sofern enthalten), und wiederholen Sie den Vorgang."

What am I doing wrong?? Or do I miss something??

Answer (score 0):

Please use PhpStorm run as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have `git` in the terminal's PATH environment variable. If you look for "terminal" in the *Settings* dialogue you can use the *Environment Variables* section to tweak that. Mine is empty and I have *Include system environment variables* checked, which I believe it's the default.

[image: Include system environment variables]